# New version of biber+biblatex problem with pagetotal string

Tags: biblatex, biber, languages

after `biblatex` was updated to 3.8 and `biber` to 2.8 I have problem with `pagetotal` string translation to polish in bibliography. MWE (compiled with `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
  author  = {Some, Author},
  title   = {Some title},
  date    = {2017},
  pagetotal   = {150}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello \cite{mybook}.
\end{document}
```

now with updated `biber` and `biblatex` it produces incorrect `pagetotal` string:
[image: new result]

while old biber and biblatex produced good one:
[image: old result]

The same applies to lithuanian language, and perhaps other languages/fields. Also the same result is when using `babel` + `pdflatex`.

Is it a bug? What is a workaround for this?

Comment: I couldn't check the reason for the change of behavior with the update. But, for the time being `\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{pagetotals={s\adddot},}` should help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following discussions in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/534 `\mkpagetotal` was changed to use dedicated `pagetotal` bibstrings. In older versions `\mkpagetotal` used the normal `page` bibstrings that were ungrammatical in some (mainly Scandinavian) languages.
The Polish language file has not been updated with the appropriate translations for `pagetotal` etc.
You could define them directly in the document with

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
  pagetotal  = {s\adddot},
  pagetotals = {s\adddot},
}
```

If you would like to share the correct strings for Polish with the developers that would be appreciated.

Additionally, there was a bug relating to `pagetotal` in `biblatex` 3.8a that is fixed in version 3.9. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/653

Comment: thanks. I uploaded edited polish.lbx [here](https://ufile.io/ikit4).

Comment: @andc Thank you. Can you open an issue at the github bug tracker and post the `.lbx` file in plain text there, please? I am not keen on downloading a `.zip` from a file sharing website.