# Biblatex pagetotals localization

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I'm writing a document in Italian with xetex and polyglossia, bibliography with biblatex/biber, nature style (but the issue happens with numeric too, at least).

Is it normal that I get bold *pagetotals* strings in the bibliography? here's an example

[image: bold pagetotals]

I don't know, it doesn't seem something that should be bold and I kind of expected a simple string like that would be automatically localized.

I can fix it with

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  pagetotals = {pagine},
}
```

but I'm worried it's the symptom of some other problem.

Here's a minimal example that reproduces the issue

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe}

\begin{document}
Here's some citation\cite{knuth}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**mwe.bib**

```
@book{knuth,
  address = {Reading, MA},
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  title = {Sorting and Searching: The Art of Computer Programming Volume 3},
  year = 1973,
  pagetotal = {800}
}
```

Compile it with

```
xelatex mwe.tex
biber mwe
xelatex mwe.tex
```

Now that I looked at the logs I see there's a warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'pagetotals' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'knuth' on input line 13.
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg sure, see the edit, there's also a warning about undefined *pagetotals*, but where does that string come from? It's `pagetotal` in the bib file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 3.8 `biblatex` introduced dedicated bibstrings for the `pagetotal` field (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/534, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/546). This became necessary because in some languages (Swedish) the string for "[on] pages 6--12" is not the same as in "230 pages".

Earlier all instances of 'page' used the `page` bibstring, but now there is also `pagetotal`, its plural version is `pagetotals` (there are also `columntotal`, `columntotals`, ... for all known pagination types). Unfortunately not all localisations have these strings yet, because we did not want to assume that `pagetotal` and `page` coincide in all languages.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  pagetotal  = {pagina},
  pagetotals = {pagine},
}
```

Is indeed the correct 'fix' (assuming that in Italian 'on pages 20-40' is the same as '240 pages'). But please by all means, drop the developers a line and tell them what the correct strings are so they can be included (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues). At the moment the [Italian localisation](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/italian.lbx) misses a few strings, so help would definitely be appreciated.

There was a nasty bug in version 3.8 of `biblatex` that prevented `pagetotal` from being used properly, but that was resolved in version 3.9. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/653. So if you are running a version <3.9, you should consider updating before trying to use `pagetotal`.

See also [New version of biber+biblatex problem with pagetotal string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402697/35864)

Comment: Thank you, I'm on 3.10 so I should be safe about those bugs. Will open an issue about the translation. By the way, do you know if is there a way to define both extended and abbreviated strings with something like `\DefineBibliographyStrings` ? I tried the syntax used in `italian.lbx` `pagetotals            = {{pagine}{pp\adddot}}` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @filippo You can't define the long and short versions with `\DefineBibliographyStrings`, that command supports only one string. To define both versions you need `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`,  but that command can only be used from `.lbx` files. So you can only define one version from your document, if you want to define both you need an `.lbx` file.

Comment: Hehe I completely missed it was `Declare` instead of `Define`, thanks again